# Add members of initializer_list to std::list in C++

Tags: c++, list, c++11, collections

I know that one can initialize a `std::list` from an `initializer_list` in a constructor, like so:

```
class Foo
{
    std::list<int> list;
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> init)
    {
        list = init;
    }
};
```

However, is there also a way to later add all elements of an `initializer_list` to the list, without creating a new `list` object, and without using a loop or iterator? So in other words: Can I use a member function of `std::list` directly? I tried with `insert()`, but failed because of invalid parameter types.

So in my example above I am looking for something like this:

```
list.insert(init);  // or something similar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`list.insert(list.end(), init);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)

Comment: with `assign()`, but it replace the previous content

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks, that solves my problem. If you post that as answer, I will happily accept it :)